# IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type Error during OneHotEncoding

Tags: python, dataframe, scikit-learn, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding

I have a dataframe containing categorical variables which I'd like to apply OneHotEncoder. My problem is solved using LabelEncoder before OneHotEncoder but it does not make sense to me since with the latest updates OneHotEncoder accepts strings for categorical variables.

Example dataframe you can test the code on :

```py
data = pd.DataFrame({'col1': {0: 'ab321', 1: 'ab568', 2: 'mkld78'},
 'col2': {0: 'Red', 1: 'Blue', 2: 'Green'},
 'col3': {0: 'First', 1: 'Second', 2: 'Third'},
 'col4': {0: 'Wisconsin', 1: 'California', 2: 'Portland'},
 'col5': {0: 'a', 1: 'f', 2: 'g'},
 'col6': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3},
 'target': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 1}})
```

Here's what I tried:

I have tried both using both the index values and the names of the columns to solve the error:

```py
#Index
# OneHotEncoding

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#Load data
train = pd.read_csv("data_train.csv")
test = pd.read_csv("data_test.csv")

X= train.drop(["target"], axis = 1)
y= train["target"]
# Filter categorical columns
categorical_columns = ["col1","col2","col3","col4","col5"]
categorical_indexes = np.where(X.dtypes == 'object')[0]

# OHE
ohe = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = categorical_columns)
# reshape data
for index in categorical_indexes:
    X.iloc[:,index] = ohe.fit_transform(X.iloc[:,index].values.reshape(-1,1))
```

---

```py
#Column Names

# OneHotEncoding

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

train = pd.read_csv("data_train.csv")
test = pd.read_csv("data_test.csv")

X= train.drop(["target"], axis = 1)
y= train["target"]

# Filter categorical columns
categorical_columns = ["col1","col2","col3","col4","col5"]
categorical_indexes = np.where(X.dtypes == 'object')[0]

# OHE
ohe = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = categorical_columns)
# reshape data
for column in categorical_columns:
    X[column] = ohe.fit_transform(X[column].values.reshape(-1,1))
```

Error Traceback:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-17c86bf649e2> in <module>
     11 # reshape data
     12 for index in categorical_indexes:
---> 13     X.iloc[:,index] = ohe.fit_transform(X.iloc[:,index].values.reshape(-1,1))
     14 

c:\users\m\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_encoders.py in fit_transform(self, X, y)
    622         self._validate_keywords()
    623 
--> 624         self._handle_deprecations(X)
    625 
    626         if self._legacy_mode:

c:\users\m\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_encoders.py in _handle_deprecations(self, X)
    453                 n_features = X.shape[1]
    454                 sel = np.zeros(n_features, dtype=bool)
--> 455                 sel[np.asarray(self.categorical_features)] = True
    456                 if sum(sel) == 0:
    457                     self.categories_ = []

IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

Comment: Can you share all the relevant code, including the parts involving the DataFrame(s)? See: [mcve]. Aside from that, just from looking at it i’m pretty sure your use of `np.where()` in `categorical_indexes` is incorrect.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile added my code from scratch can you take a look at it now ?

Comment: Can you share some example data? It’s impossible to run the code otherwise.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the concept of the `OnehotEncoder`. The way to use it is to fit it on the whole training set.

Use this:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'col1': {0: 'ab321', 1: 'ab568', 2: 'mkld78'},
 'col2': {0: 'Red', 1: 'Blue', 2: 'Green'},
 'col3': {0: 'First', 1: 'Second', 2: 'Third'},
 'col4': {0: 'Wisconsin', 1: 'California', 2: 'Portland'},
 'col5': {0: 'a', 1: 'f', 2: 'g'},
 'col6': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3},
 'target': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 1}})


# OneHotEncoding

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

train = data.iloc[0:2,:]
test = data.iloc[2:,:]

X= train.drop(["target"], axis = 1)
y= train["target"]

# Filter categorical columns
categorical_columns = ["col1","col2","col3","col4","col5"]
categorical_indexes = np.where(X.dtypes == 'object')[0]

# OHE
ohe = OneHotEncoder()
X_ = ohe.fit_transform(X)

X_
# <2x12 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
#  with 12 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Comment: What if I want to use categorical_features parameter in OneHotEncoder? I I get the same error when I put categorical_features parameter